# inheritance with where in C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Can somebody please explain me the meaning of the function below? Sorry, I am more VB developer and I cant understand the syntax below. Convertor tools convert it meaningless into VB code.

- I dont understand the usage of T
- I dont understand the inheritance with Where T

  ```
   public static string ValidateSeName<T>(this T entity, string seName, string name, bool ensureNotEmpty)
           where T : BaseEntity, ISlugSupported
  {
  }
  ```

Where this function is called, caller function looks like as below. What happened to the first parameter with this T entity, it is not used as parameter? what is the purpose of it?

```
  model.SeName = category.ValidateSeName(model.SeName, category.Name, true);
```

It will be helpful if you can give me to equal code in VB as well.
thanks

Comment: where is a type constraint. Essentially the only types that can be used by ValidateSetName are of type BaseEntity, and ISlugSupported. More info @https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into extension methods as well.  The first parameter isn't passed, which is why it's missing from the calling declaration.

Comment: Also if you are not familiar with C# syntax.. copy paste the code and goto Telerik Converter site and paste the code in their converter selecting C#ToVB

Comment: The 'where' clause says that T should derive from BaseEntity and implement ISlugSupported. At the calling site the syntax is because the method is an extension method(note the 'this' keyword in the signature). the type 'T' is infered from the type of the 'category' variable.

Comment: thanks for the answers but why are those down votes? If I knew the name, I wouldnt duplicate the question. if someone sees the usage first time, wouldnt know the name of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a generic extension method, [VB.NET supports it also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx):

```
Public Module MyExtensionMethods

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ValidateSeName(Of T As { BaseEntity, ISlugSupported })(entity As T, seName As String, name As String, ensureNotEmpty As Boolean) As String

    End Function

End Module
```

The constraint defined in `where` (in C#) or with `As` (in VB.NET) has nothing to do with inheritance. It's just tells the compiler that only these types are allowed for `T`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. as I understand, where function is called, type should be given, correct? but in this case above, I dont see how the type of the the "entity" is given? when I debug, I see that "entity" is having the type of the "category". how is the logic here?

Comment: @batmaci: `where` is not a function and it has nothing to do with `Enumerable.Where` which is a LINQ method. The C# `where` contextual  keyword let you specify one or multiple [constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).  So it restricts the types which `T` can be. Note that `T` is just an arbitrary name, it could also be `Willy`. It's like a variable for the actual type.

Comment: The caller specifies the type. So if you call this method `category.ValidateSeName(model.SeName, category.Name, true);`, then the type of `T` is `Category` which seems to be a class that inherits `BaseEntity` and implements `ISlugSupported`. Note that the type is inferred in this case from the type of the variable `category` because it's an extension method, so `category` is actually the first argument to the method. You can also make it more explicit: `category.ValidateSeName<Category>(model.SeName, category.Name, true)`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, exactly i was  wondering this why it wasnt called like you wrote in the end. So now it is clear.